# how to use a project as a library api in another project in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a splitview project using fragment in android, where i used some method to generateviews, define width of the splits and a method to set the background colour, here is my java code:

```
public class SplitviewActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        Left.OnButtonClickListener {

    LinearLayout LEFT, RIGHT, leftfragmentln, rightfragmentln;
    Right rightFr;
    Left leftFr;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //reduced the Gray Bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // initializes the objects
        initializer();

        // sets the size of the two sides, give the ration here
        setSize(20, 80);
        // sets the colour of the two sides
        setColor(Color.BLUE, Color.RED);

    }

    public void initializer() {
        LEFT = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnLeft);
        RIGHT = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnRight);
        leftfragmentln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnLeftFragment);
        rightfragmentln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnRightFragment);
        rightFr = (Right) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.view_right);
        leftFr = (Left) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.view_left);

    }

    public void setColor(int leftColor, int rightColor) {

        // for landscape mode
        if ((rightFr != null) && rightFr.isInLayout() && (leftFr != null)
                && leftFr.isInLayout()) {

            LEFT.setBackgroundColor(leftColor);
            RIGHT.setBackgroundColor(rightColor);
        } else {
            // for portrait mode
            RIGHT.setBackgroundColor(rightColor);

        }

    }

    public void setSize(float leftsize, float rightsize) {

        // for landscape mode
        if ((rightFr != null) && rightFr.isInLayout() && (leftFr != null)
                && leftFr.isInLayout()) {

            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams par1 = (LayoutParams) LEFT
                    .getLayoutParams();

            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams par2 = (LayoutParams) RIGHT
                    .getLayoutParams();
            par1.weight = rightsize;
            par2.weight = leftsize;

        }

    }

    // a method to add view in a blank xml programatically
    public void setView(View leftView, View rightView) {
        if ((rightFr != null) && rightFr.isInLayout() && (leftFr != null)
                && leftFr.isInLayout()) {
            leftfragmentln.addView(leftView);
            rightfragmentln.addView(rightView);
        } else {

            rightfragmentln.addView(rightView);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickButton(String s) {

        if ((rightFr != null) && rightFr.isInLayout()) {
            rightFr.setText(s);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RightActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", s);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

now I want to use this code as a library in another project and just want to call these methods to generate views, define width and setbackground colour. I have tried in different ways, but nothing was able to solve my problem. Can any one help me with a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

I currently do this with a plain java project.
To include I configured in the build path

a)
Project:

just add your project

b)
Order and Export

select (check) your project

Comment: Your suggession works fine, I can create object from my library project, but all i want to know that how can i call those methods in my new projects? I called but it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

Right click on projects in the project pane -> properties -> Java build path -> Projects or Libraries one of them !

Answer (score 0):

Create your new android project in Eclipse then go to your existing project and

Properties => Android => is library project => tick this

Then in the new project go to

Properties => Android => add library project then select your lib project from the list

You must leave the lib project open. This same method is used by Facebook and actionbar Sherlock.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on you another project  -> properties -> Select the type of filter as android ==>then go to library ==>click On add ===>select your project.